# attempt to read property "xxx" on null

Tags: eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-8

I have created a database and model according to various instructions for many to many relationships but still error

Divisi model :

```
public function status()

{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Status','id_status','id');
}
```

}

Status model :

```
public function divisi()

{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Divisi','id_divisi','id');
}
```

blade view :

```
  <tr>
    <td><a href="{{ route('pengajuan.show',['pengajuan' => $pengajuan->id]) }}">
        {{$pengajuan->nama_project}}</a></td>
    <td>{{$pengajuan->divisis->nama_divisi}}</td>
    <td>{{$pengajuan->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$pengajuan->tanggal_pengajuan}}</td>
    <td>{{$pengajuan->total}}</td>
    <td>{{$pengajuan->statuses->nama_status}}</td>
    <td>{{$pengajuan->keterangan}}</td>
    </li>
```

[the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL0aO.png)

[my ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvQhE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<td>{{$pengajuan->statuses->nama_status}}</td>
```

to

```
<td>{{$pengajuan->status()->nama_status}}</td>
```

also

```
<td>{{$pengajuan->divisis->nama_divisi}}</td>
```

to

```
 <td>{{$pengajuan->divisi()->nama_divisi}}</td>
```

so that will work

Comment: thank youuuuu :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain the error to you
so the error say's that your trying to access something in something doesn't exists (null) , its like that you have an assoc array and trying to get unexists key